# I cannot find the android.jks file shown in the tutorial

Tags: java, android, jks

I'm trying to get a Release Certificate Fingerprint for my app. I was following [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) tutorial. In the **Sign Your Release Build** section of the tutorial, I saw android.jks used in the `Key store Path`.

Problem is, I can't find it ANYWHERE in my computer. I'm using Win 7 & I have looked into my ***.android*** directory as well as in ***Java/bin*** directory in C:\Program Files(x86), but nowhere could I find `android.jks` file or any `.jks` file for that matter.

When I try **Generate Signed APK**, even that requires the .jks file.

I have my `debug.keystore` and `default.keyset` in my **.android** directory, but I can't seem to find the **android.jks** file anywhere

Please help

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own .jks or keystore file that you will use to sign your apk. You can simply use keytool to do that (Refer http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-for.html for my detailed personal blog post on how to do that)

As per what I see in the link you have Studio provides a way to create one too (If you don't want to use command line and keytool) (Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode)
The path that you see in the image on the tutorials page is the path where your android.jks will be created.

Basically you are creating a self signed certificate that you will use to sign your apk before uploading it to play store.

Comment: I did it using command line. Where is the file supposed to be stored?

Comment: You can give file name and path in the command but if you haven't it should be created in your users home directory with name `.keystore`.